# How to obtain the interval limits from a decision tree with scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, tree-structure

Say I am using the titanic dataset, with the variable age only:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://www.openml.org/data/get_csv/16826755/phpMYEkMl')[["age", "survived"]]
data = data.replace('?', np.nan)
data = data.fillna(0)
print(data)
```

the result:

```py
         age  survived
0         29         1
1     0.9167         1
2          2         0
3         30         0
4         25         0
...      ...       ...
1304    14.5         0
1305       0         0
1306    26.5         0
1307      27         0
1308      29         0

[1309 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now I train a decision tree to predict survival from age:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
tree_model.fit(data['age'].to_frame(),data["survived"])
```

And if I print the structure of the tree:

```py
from sklearn import tree
print(tree.export_text(tree_model))
```

I obtain:

```py
|--- feature_0 <= 0.08
|   |--- class: 0
|--- feature_0 >  0.08
|   |--- feature_0 <= 8.50
|   |   |--- feature_0 <= 1.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |--- feature_0 >  1.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- feature_0 >  8.50
|   |   |--- feature_0 <= 60.25
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |--- feature_0 >  60.25
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
```

These means that the final division for every node is:

0-0.08 ; 0.08-1.50; 1.50-8.50 ; 8.50-60; >60

My question is, how can I capture those limits in an array that looks like this:

```py
[-np.inf, 0.08, 1.5, 8.5, 60, np.inf]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision classifier, in this case `tree_model` has an attribute called `tree_` which allows access to low level attributes.

```py
print(tree_model.tree_.threshold)

array([ 0.08335, -2.     ,  8.5    ,  1.5    , -2.     , -2.     ,
       60.25   , -2.     , -2.     ])
```

```py
print(tree_model.tree_.feature)

array([ 0, -2,  0,  0, -2, -2,  0, -2, -2], dtype=int64)
```

The arrays `feature` and `threshold` only apply to split nodes. The values for leaf nodes in these arrays are therefore arbitrary.

To get the division/threshold of a feature, you can filter the threshold using the `feature` array.

```py
threshold = tree_model.tree_.threshold
feature = tree_model.tree_.feature
feature_threshold = threshold[feature == 0]
thresholds = sorted(feature_threshold)
print(thresholds)

[0.08335000276565552, 1.5, 8.5, 60.25]
```

To have `np.inf`, you need to add it yourself.

```py
thresholds = [-np.inf] + thresholds + [np.inf]
print(thresholds)

[-inf, 0.08335000276565552, 1.5, 8.5, 60.25, inf]
```

Reference: [Understanding the decision tree structure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py).